# Angular 2: Input properties change after url change

Tags: angular

I have a question, relating to architecture with Angular2.

Basically, what I am trying to do is create an application with 2 main views. The first view, will be the index view where there is a searchbar and some filters.

For the sake of an example, let's assume that we have a parent component and a child component that contains the searchbar and one filter.

I need the child component searchbar and filters to be populated by the URL. So I am using Input() properties.

In the parent component, I am subscribing to the URL parameters and re-populating the Input() properties when the URL changes.
In the child component, I am listening to ngOnChanges for changes of the Inputs. 
Also, in the child component, I will be listening to changes coming from user Input. Those changes, will be causing the emitting of an event and the parent component will be changing the url as a response to those events, so the Input properties are going to "change" again to whatever their value was before (Basically, I am navigating to the same Component, with different queryParams in the URL).

This seems weird to me - but maybe I am wrong since Angular 2 is new to me. Have you got any ideas on how to architect an app that needs to have child components with Input properties that populate a form and listen to both URL changes and changes to those Input properties?

Wherever I find articles, they seem to either be talking about the router or about Input properties but never about both and I am wondering - Has nobody implemented a search app with results and filters/facets and values that need to appear in the URL as parameters in Angular 2 yet? :) Seems to me like a very common use-case.

Comment: Very unclear, does it change anything while changing the url? Demonstrate with example.

Comment: Hi Roman, I understand my question sounds unclear. I just found it hard to describe what I am trying to do. I will try to provide an example in a repository when I find some time.